# Error after installing joosco into joomla 2.5 to integrate with Alfresco

Tags: joomla2.5, alfresco

I am using joomla 2.5.9. I just installed Alfresco Community 4.2. I want to integrate both joomla and Alfresco. So I installed the plugin and the component of Joosco Extension v0.1 and follow the installation tips which were given inside the joosco .rar.

But it always gives this error **"Fatal error: Call to undefined method plgAuthenticationJoosco::onUserAuthenticate() in D:\xampp\htdocs\ecm_sample\libraries\joomla\user\authentication.php on line 306"**

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Joosco plugin is not installed or the respective function is missing.

Check inside `/plugins/authentication/joosco` (or a folder that resembles the name joosco). If it's not there, than it's not installed.

If it's there, than it must contian a file like joosco.php> The respective class must have a function called onUserAuthenticate().

That is all this error all about.

---

**EDIT:** It looks to me that this plugin was designed for Joomla! 1.5. You need to look for something compatible with Joomla! 2.5, try the JED or the forum.

Comment: It is installed there and joosco.php too. but there is no function called onUserAuthenticate().   And this comes when i logout from back-end and again trying to login to the back-end

Comment: If you feel you have the skills, I would fork the project joosco, put it on github and do the changes there. I offer to look over the code if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank You very much for your words. And I just saw the later part of your answer. I'm at office and here I don't have permission to put it on github. For the tome been I'll try JED or the forum.

Comment: Hello there, still i couldn't find a extension to replace joosco. Do you know any extension??

Comment: My issue is mentioned in this forum also. But there is no solution http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=947365

Comment: When i installed the joosco plugin successfully and trying to access it through administrator --> Components --> com-joosco, it gives "404 - An error has occurred.
Component not found

Return to Control Panel" error. I tried again with joosco because they say that it is compatible with joomla 1.5 and above.

Comment: It'c can't be compatible with 2.5 if it's build with on 1.5. Some things have changed. As I said, if you try to fixit and post the code on github, I can give you some pointers on how to update the plugin to 2.5

Comment: I tried component which is dropped in the below location, that is also compatible with 1.5 i guess.  http://thierry.frutieaux.free.fr/Joomla%201.5/Composants,%20modules/Afresco%20-%20GED/    But in the front-end it gives "Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 4: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: p line 3 and html in D:\xampp\htdocs\sample1.5\components\com_alfresco\models\abstract.php on line 165" error

Comment: Please understand that I can't give you 1:1 support. You need to figure some things out and when you have problems search for similar error. If the error / problem you are facing it's not already asked on stackoverflow feel free to create another question and to post there the snippet of code that is causing you problems. Please consider that  here we are building an archive of questions and answers that are useful to people and situations beyond that of the original asker.

Comment: yes I understand. I'll try to upload the code in the github. Also i searched on above mentioned error. But there were no completed answers.